# Firebase Swift Package missing from Xcode package installer

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase

I am trying to install Firebase into my xCode project. I clicked file > add packages and only 12 "Apple Swift Packages" show up, and if I search for https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk.git it returns 0 results. Could there be a setting or something that is preventing xCode from finding external packages? Is there another way to install firebase into my project (without using CocoaPods)?

Comment: Did you go into Xcode settings and add you GitHub account?

Comment: If by "add your github account" you mean going to Xcode > Preferences > Accounts and adding my github credentials then yes

Comment: Hmm. Then I don't know. I paste that url into the Xcode package add screen and I get the firebase package

Comment: @Paulw11 I've never added my github credentials to XCode to add a SPM library. I just created a brand new XCode project, am not logged into git and it still seems to work? Is that something new? Just curious

Comment: No, it shouldn't be necessary. I was just tyrying to think of things that would cause a problemm

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you'll need to agree to the terms and conditions in your developer account

XCode->Settings->Accounts

Your developer AppleID should be listed in the left column and selecting it will show details on the right. Their may be a message indicating the issue - you may need to re-authenticate as well. While there, ensure the signing certificates are valid.

You can also manually log into the [Apple developer portal](https://developer.apple.com/account) and see if it presents terms and conditions that need to be signed.

As long as all of those are in place, when pasting the link in the question into XCode (14+) it should look like this

[image]

Also - and this is strictly IMO, I've had very good success with CocoaPod installs and Firebase. I find it easier to update/modify libraries as they change. You may want to give it a whirl to see if it's easier for you.

Finally - there have been issues with Free developer accounts or ones that were paid and then are now free. Limited amount of devices for example, an expired account or even an expired credit card on a paid account.

Last suggestion - if it's available, you can reset the package cache in XCode in the File menu

[image]